Are calories an appropriate measurement of energy for biological systems?
According to this source, a calorie is an inappropriate unit to quantify the energy contained in food because a "calorie is heat energy" and "humans don't absorb photons" but instead absorb matter.
Doesn't this statement fundamentally misunderstand the concept of energy? Just because a thermic instrument is used to determine the energetic content of something, it doesn't mean that energy can only be utilized thermally.

You should state the source. I would not be surprised if it is bad. But you are also yourself mistaken in the understanding. While it is definitely the case that such kinds of (stationary) energy differences, even in foods, correspond necessarily to differences in rest mass, in practice the chemical bonds in foods are never measured by measuring those rest mass differences. It would be too small and inconsequential, just managing to stay in accordance with Einstein's energy momentum mass relation. Anyway, eating food entails absorbing the energy in food.

The source is random folks on the internet so I don't give it any credibility but it does make me think. The only reason I brought up Einstein was to demonstrate that "humans don't absorb energy, they absorb matter" is a conceptually flawed statement that misunderstands the idea of energy itself (since matter and energy are interchangeable).

If you want to get a laugh out of someone, try telling a biochemist that it's inappropriate to apply the concept of energy to biological systems.

@d_b I can't tell which side of that opinion you are on

About your source, he went off the rails when he said "calories are a measure of heat energy, specifically, and only heat energy". A calorie (as used in nutrition) is 4184 joules. It may be defined in terms of a thermal measurement (heating a volume of water), but it can equally be used to measure other kinds of energy (electrical potential energy, gravitic potential energy, or whatever). Just as a joule is defined in terms of work (force applied over distance) but can be used to measure other kinds of energy just as well.

Arguing from that semantic distinction to the idea that energy is not related to weight gain is then far into the weeds.

Actually he lost me with that crazy outfit, but let's talk about science rather than wardrobe.

@ThePhoton yeah the outfit is insane. To your point, is it fair to say that energy, as a concept, is like distance in the sense that many different units exist to quantify it but the nature of the unit speaks more the convention as opposed to characterization? In other words, we use yards to measure a football field but that doesn't mean a field 100 yards long is a football field. A unit of measurement quantifies but does not characterize something.

Put differently, energy is simply a framework within which we can use mathematics to predict phenomenon; the application of this framework dictates the units of measurement, not the other way around.

Why this was closed?

@JonBehnken did you mean to say "inappropriate" or rather the opposite?

@icv I edited the post for clarity, perhaps it will reopen. I probably should’ve said “inappropriate” in the title because that’s actually my question.

I won't answer your whole question (which is more about biology than physics) but I will address some misconceptions you seem to have that are explainable by physics:

the total energy released (which includes the mass of the food)

It doesn't. The only energy released by your body when digesting food is chemical energy. The mass of the food after breaking it down into its chemical components remains so close to the same that the difference is immeasurable.
If you want to convert matter to energy you need to annihilate that matter with an anti-matter collision.

Didn't Einstein show that energy and matter are related and interchangeable?

He did but it's irrelevant to the energy exchanges that happen in digestion of food because the mass of the food is unchanged by this process.

When the total amount of energy consumed exceeds the amount of energy that contributes to metabolic and physical work, the internal energy of the biological system is in disequilibrium (i.e. excess ATP) and the organisms response is to deposit this excess into physical tissue.

What's happening here isn't the body converting energy into matter and vice versa. It's the body using excess energy to make chemical bonds between existing atoms to form fat molecules (for example) and to store them in fat cells. There isn't any new matter being produced by this process.

Thanks for your explanations and apologies for the off-topic post. So the mass of food is unchanged, I can understand that. It's the excess energy from the bonds in the food that is used to create new chemical bonds with existing atoms. Since additional mass is available due to the presence of food, the formation of new bonds results in more matter retained within the body, is that right?

I'll also add that I only brought up Einstein as means to conceptually characterize energy as "the capacity for doing work" which is a response to the claim that "humans don't absorb energy, they absorb mass". Differentiating between "energy" and "mass" is irrelevant isn't it? Humans do absorb the chemical energy in foods and store it as mass.

You should cite where you saw the claim that "humans don't absorb energy, they absorb mass". That sounds like non-mainstream science but without context it's hard to know what they really meant by it.

@JonBehnken that is not how that works. Humans absorb the whole glucose sugar molecule, that has the basic rest mass and chemical energy, and then when you use up the energy, it will come out as carbon dioxide gas and water, which is later expelled. That mass is expelled. Einstein's relation must hold; this means that the sugar molecule (plus the oxygen gas's mass) is just that incredibly tiny amount heavier than the carbon dioxide gas and water that the reaction produce, just that exact amount equalling the chemical energy. It is nicer to just talk about the chemical energy alone.

@naturallyInconsistent if the person consumes more calories than they expend, and is therefore "putting on weight", that added weight comes from food (and air) that is ingested but not expelled.

@ThePhoton I've added a source to the post. It's very much from non-mainstream science but I'm trying to understand these fundamental concepts and expose my own deficits through the lens of what these claims get wrong.

@ThePhoton that is a retention of huge rest mass and tiny chemical energy; while Einstein's energy momentum mass relation is upheld in everything, that is not the main contributor to the "putting on weight"

@naturallyInconsistent but the retention of the rest mass is predicated on the presence of the chemical energy, no? Perhaps I incorrectly invoked Einstein; I was using Einstein's theory more to try and dismiss the idea that we should disambiguate between mass and chemical energy in human systems because they're equivalent, but I may have been wrong.

@JonBehnken that is correct. Which is why it was particularly unfortunate that you brought in Einstein. If you did not, then we could have simply argued that food is stored in the body. We store not just the chemical energy, but the very thing itself that has that chemical energy. In any case, counting calories is a correct thing to do.

Given that the caloric content of food is determined by oxidizing (burning) it in a calorimeter, yes, the calorie is a perfectly fine unit to use.

@naturallyInconsistent so let's use the example of 3,500 calories equals one pound of fat; is it accurate to say that 3,500 calories represents the energy required to synthesize 1 pound of fat and is predicated on the fact that 1 pound of physical matter is available as a vehicle for storing that energy?

@naturallyInconsistent, yes I understand that the energy we use is chemical energy. My point is that you said "the mass is expelled" and that's not entirely true. Some of it is used to grow our bodies.

It is totally irrelevant if you measure energy in calories or Joulem since you can just change the one unit in the others. Chemical reactions change masse very insignificant, so E= mc^2 has no influence in biology. If the energy content  of food has any influence on health is not a physics question.
